# Java Connect Datasource never ends

Tags: java, unit-testing, datasource, glassfish-3, junit4

I was writing a JUnit test trying to test the connection to a SqlServer Database (i know, i know... i shouldn't unit testing for databases). The question is, I've already setup the datasource in glassfish, in fact, ping test "succeeded". But!, when i try this:

Note: The configuration is: Unit testing from Local Glassfish (where ping OK), Remote DataBase

```
@Test
public void simpleConnect() {

    try {
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("MyDataSource");
        Connection con = dataSource.getConnection();
        assertTrue(con != null && dataSource != null);
    }
    catch (NamingException ex) {
        fail("Cannot get connection: " + ex);
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        fail("Cannot get connection: " + ex);
    }

}
```

Nothing happens, the test never ends, NO throws Ok or Fail. I don't know exactly if I really gets the connection.

Comment: +1 for "I know, I shouldn't do this". :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the idea was initially try to test the connection to the datasource and well, i was trying JUnit, but doesn't work in my case, so, i found a solution using a JSP page.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.SQLException"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="javax.sql.DataSource"%>
<%@page import="javax.naming.InitialContext"%>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
                   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Test DataSource Connection</title>
  </head>
<body>
<h1>Connecting to Pooled Database</h1>  
<%
    InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
    DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("MyDataSource");
    Connection connection = ds.getConnection();

    if (connection == null) {
        throw new SQLException("Error establishing connection!");
    }

    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    ResultSet result = null;
    stmt = connection.prepareStatement("{call StoredProcedure(?,?)}");
    stmt.setString(1, "1");
    stmt.setString(2, "2");
    result = stmt.executeQuery();

    while (result.next()) {
        out.print(result.getString(1) + "<br>");
    }
%>

<h2>DataSource Working!</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

When you run the JSP this will retrieve the resultset of the call to the stored procedure. Obviously you can replace the call with a simple query (select * from table)

If maybe you need info about how to create, connect, and configure a datasource, look this link:http://netbeans.dzone.com/connection-pooling-glassfish-nb

Answer (score 0):

Try to close the connection.

```
finally{ con.close; }
```

Usually it's a no go to do Junit-tests on a datasource, is it really needed?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the test which obviously causes it to hang. I suggest to run it in a debugger to isolate the line in which it hangs.

Comment: never finds the datasource in the line: DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("MyDataSource"); , looping around that line, just appears an INFO: "com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.CommonClassLoaderServiceImpl findDerbyClient
INFO: Cannot find javadb client jar file, derby jdbc driver will not be available by default."

Comment: There must be some code that puts `MyDataSource` into the `Context`. Please edit your question and show us what that does look like.

Comment: And why do you use `ctx.lookup()` at all? Why don't you create a datasource in your unit test?

Comment: Actually, I'm not using anything else, I found a workaround to test the data source with a jsp. For the moment is not optimal but enough to resolve the connection test. I will publish it , maybe, someone would need it.

Comment: That can't be right; if no one puts the object in the context, you'd get a `NamingException`.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to the JNDI context of a remote Glassfish server need to pass properties to the InitialContext constructor:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "localhost");
props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);
```

You can call this an integration test not a unit test and you aren't breaking the law!

Personally I would not use this approach of looking up a DataSource from a remote Glassfish instance in an integration test, I would create a DataSource using [Commons DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/) or similar so your test works when GlassFish is down.

Comment: after the initialContext, I added the connection code, But, is doing the same.